# Schedule job on SQL Server Agent to stop

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-agent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server Agent Job Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588599/sql-server-agent-job-timeout)

Can a scheduled job on SQL Server 2005 be scheduled to be stopped if it runs more than a certain number of hours? Just like the scheduled task in windows?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588599/sql-server-agent-job-timeout

Duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

There is sp_stop_job procedure that stops the jobs.
see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182793 for details.

Comment: -1: he asked how to stop the jobs automatically if they take too long.

Comment: the question was edited at least 2 times after I answered.

Comment: Original: "Can a scheduled job on MS SQL 2005 be scheduled to be stopped if it runs more than a certain number of hours? Just like the scheduled task in windows?"