# How to increase the timeout of a SQL Script job step?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL job running which contains 2 steps. One of them is of type (T-SQL Script) and I am facing timeout issue with it.

How can I configure the timeout for that specific job? (eventually for the job if the timeout is inherited). I use SQL Server 2008 R2

Thank you!

Comment: Why not improve the query to take less time?

Comment: What makes you think you're facing a timeout issue? - so far as I recall, a job step can run for days without changing any settings.

Comment: because the job is failing and the error is Query Timeout

Comment: The query is optimized but the data size is too big

Comment: Try [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1589284/1057791), it seems like it's the only option to control the timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding there is no option to set time-ot for T-Sql script in SQL jobs.Mainy this will happen when ther is hughe increase in the records of the underlying sql script.

check this article.

http://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2012/07/16/sql-server-query-time-out-when-referencing-data-on-a-linked-server-2/